# Listing skills on resume

Tags: resume, recruitment, careers, skills

I want to know if I should list technical on which I have knowledge, familiarity and reasonable level of expertise, but no work experience in my resume. If yes than how to list them in a resume so as it gives a clear picture of my to the recruiters.

Comment: What does your current research indicate? An answer to this question has probably been answered a dozen times.

Comment: Possibly related: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/17322/how-to-show-skills-through-evidence

Answer (score 2):

Your work experience is the critical component of your resume. If you are brand new on the job market and with no experience, then your education is important.

Your skills are of no relevance if you are not prepared to discuss how you made use of them in your past or present work experience or how you can make use of them on behalf of a prospective employer at the position you are applying for.

Your resume format should go something like this

**Name**
Address
Email
Tel
LinkedIn
Github (if you did any software development that you can show)

**EDUCATION**
List your degrees

**OBJECTIVE**
Secify the kind of position you are going for

**SKILLS SET**
List your skills, as long as they are relevant to the position you are applying for For each skill,provide an example where you used that skill. Example:
- Event Planning - Planned and organized my brother's wedding. Everything went smoothly until the first person showed up :)
- Leadership - As captain of the Columbia University football team, led the team to a season that ended with a 1:9 win:loss record for the 2013 season. Our seasons are usually 0:10 :)
 
- Persuasion - Talked my Boy Scout troop into taking a shortcut into an unmapped area where we got lost for three days.It would have been four if someone had not signalled a rescue helicopter :)

**VOLUNTEER WORK EXPERIENCE**
Don't knock it. I get plenty of good experience there that I wouldn't get from my current work. As long as a prospective employer knows that I got and used my skills somewhere, they couldn't care less where I got them from as long as they know that I have them and that I know how to use them.

**WORK EXPERIENCE**
List any kind of work experience you have no matter how menial. Your prospective employer might want to know that, if anything, you can show up fr work on time.

In general, external recruiters have little interest in indivdual with no work experience. Mainly because those who have no work experience are a dime a dozen and prospective employers can get on their own individuals with zero experience with little to no effort - No way for an external recruiter to make commissions money on that. It's like trying to sell ice to Canadians in the Artic or sand in the Death Valley :)

Internal recruiters such as those who work directly for the Big Four are interested in warm bodies that they can recruit to perform work on the cheap on consulting assignments supervised by very experienced senior people.