# Should I mention PSR Coding Standard (PSR-1, PSR-2) in resume?

Tags: resume, career-development, careers

Should I mention PSR Coding Standard (PSR-1, PSR-2) in resume? It will be good for a programmer or not? Please guide me

Comment: It may be considered a skill if you are applying for a relevant position (e.g. PHP programming role). See also topics on skills in CVs: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/33793/listing-skills-on-resume . However, consider if the shop you're applying for doesn't use this standard. In general you should have the ability to use the coding standard you're assigned and/or that is decided by the team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you're hurting for resume material I wouldn't. Lots of places use PSR 1 & 2 for the coding style guidelines, but lots of places don't.

The interview would be a good place to bring it up. Ask them if they have in-house style guidelines or if they adhere to the PSRs. People always seem to need more questions to ask, that's a good one. If they use PSRs then it's easy, you already know and follow them. If they use in-house then great, you understand style guidelines and can adapt to whatever they need.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it will depend on the company etc., but be aware that it could be a negative sign.

PHP has *many* users just trying to make their own site, without any programming experience. This group is the most important audience for the 12 PSR documents, topicwise (altough no one reads it)

When hiring a professional programmer, hearing that he/she knows PSR and does *not* know/fulfil one of the topics in any way (but "boast" with others in the resume), is not a good sign.

Comment: (To clarify, I don't mean all good programmers follow all 12 PSRs strictly enough that eg. the names of the classes are the same as in the docs. But knowing what it is about and how to do it...)